# New SSD in optical Bay, Cant get boot order to select it first

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

*(fairly new to Ubuntu)*

Running 14.04 on a Mac (a1278 Mac 5.1), no dual boot just Ubuntu.

Just installed a new SSD in place of my optical drive. It was recognized, and I used "dd" to copy my existing OS to the new SSD. When looking at it in Gparted it replicates the old partitions to the new SSD, ***good right***? *(both the old and new drives have a bios_grub flag on the first partition)*

This is where my lack of knowledge comes in. When booting after the "dd", two drives came up both labeled "windows". I tried loading from each one of them, and unmounting my **original drive** in Gparted..thinking I could just force the computer into booting to the correct drive if only one is recognized. That didnt exactly work. Now when I boot my computer it defaults to a white screen. If I shut down and hold option, I can select the only drive listed *(still named windows.. sigh)*..which I am assuming is my new SSD as my old HD shows up as blank in gparted.

*I am thinking I have some boot issues with grub regardless of the new SSD, but this section is a little confusing for me.*

**Now the question**: How can I get my computer to default boot to the SSD in place of my CD Drive? I have Grub Customizer and have tried to follow directions but I cant seem to get any decent results.

Comment: Is your old hard drive still connected to your motherboard?

Comment: Did you do a whole-disk copy with `dd`, as in `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`? If so, you copied the disk and partition GUIDs, which is likely to be confusing the firmware. You can fix this by using the `-G` option to `sgdisk` on the duplicated disk, as in `sudo sgdisk -G /dev/sdb`.

Comment: Hey Rod, thanks for the tip. Though, somehow over night my laptop decided it wanted to boot to a black screen with a blinking cursor so I haven't had a chance to try out sgdisk -c. Will update when I'm functional.

Comment: Cstich: Old HD is still connected, if possible it would be nice to utilize both.